# SonarQube in Docker failes to resolve local host

Tags: docker, sonarqube, alpine-linux, sonarqube-ops

I'm attempting to set up SonarQube in Docker using an [Alpine Linux Docker Image](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine). However, when running the image, SonarQube seems to have problem resolving local host. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.2

ENV SONAR_VERSION=5.6.1 \
    SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube \
    SONARQUBE_FORCE_AUTHENTICATION=true \
    # Database configuration
    # Defaults to using H2
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=

# Http port
EXPOSE 9000

RUN apk -Uu add gnupg curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

    # pub   2048R/D26468DE 2015-05-25
    #       Key fingerprint = F118 2E81 C792 9289 21DB  CAB4 CFCA 4A29 D264 68DE
    # uid   sonarsource_deployer (Sonarsource Deployer) <infra@sonarsource.com>
    # sub   2048R/06855C1D 2015-05-25
RUN gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE

RUN set -x \
    && mkdir /opt \
    && cd /opt \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc \
    && gpg --batch --verify sonarqube.zip.asc sonarqube.zip \
    && unzip sonarqube.zip \
    && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube \
    && rm sonarqube.zip* \
    && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*

VOLUME ["$SONARQUBE_HOME/data", "$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions"]

WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY run.sh $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

**./bin/run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "${1:0:1}" != '-' ]; then
  exec "$@"
fi

exec java -jar lib/sonar-application-$SONAR_VERSION.jar \
    -Dsonar.log.console=true \
    -Dsonar.jdbc.username="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME" \
    -Dsonar.jdbc.password="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD" \
    -Dsonar.jdbc.url="$SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL" \
    -Dsonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts="$SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" \
    "$@"
```

**Docker log**

```
016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1472630204100] version[1.7.5], pid[18], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1472630204100] initializing ...
2016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1472630204100] loaded [], sites []
2016.08.31 07:56:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1472630204100] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (/dev/vda2)]], net usable_space [55gb], net total_space [59gb], types [ext4]
2016.08.31 07:56:46 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.08.31 07:56:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1472630204100] initialized
2016.08.31 07:56:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1472630204100] starting ...
2016.08.31 07:56:47 WARN   es[o.e.common.network]  failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: 05ae620efc22: 05ae620efc22: unknown error
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.<clinit>(NetworkUtils.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.createClientBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:350) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:242) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:153) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:257) [elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:46) [sonar-search-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) [sonar-process-5.6.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:81) [sonar-search-5.6.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 05ae620efc22: unknown error
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'd try creating a shell into the running container (`docker exec -i -t <containerID> /bin/bash`) and seeing if you can resolve the hostname from there, e.g. with ping, and have a look at `/etc/resolv.conf` to see how that's set up. But I thought docker took care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is no Name Service Switch file in Alpine linux, and java need one for java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost for example.

Add this line in dockerfile

```
RUN echo 'hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4' > /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Comment: Nice +1. Also interesting read: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/11#issuecomment-106233554

Answer (score 1):

Since [`InetAddress.html#getLocalHost`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost--) will "retrieving the name of the host from the system", make sure you launch your container with an hostname.

```
docker run --add-host xxx --hostname yyy
```

See [`docker run` Network Settings for `--add-host` and `--hostname` options](http://docs.docker.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings)

Comment: But it has a hostname, albeit an auto-generated one, that should be valid inside the docker world, and should be set up in /etc/hosts even without the --add-host.

Comment: @Rup yes, I was thinking more about this old issue https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/68#issuecomment-60494711

Answer (score 0):

I run into a same like issue on k8s and resolved by providing an environment variable to force the DB bind to 127.0.0.1

```
kubectl run sonarqube --image=sonarqube --port=9092 --env="SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dh2.bindAddress=127.0.0.1"
```